# HP 1920-48 - WebLogin addresses/interfaces

Tags: switch, vlan

I'm new to this forum and HP's 1920 switching technology.

What I'd like to do is getting a 1920 configured with 2 VLANs (intranet and adminnet), but with WebLoging enabled in only one (adminnet) of them.

So far I configured the 1920 with two port based VLANs and assigned one static adddress to each.
I'm performing the routing between these two VLANs by a seperate firewall which works fine for me.

My problem this in the Web GUI's wizzard in the "Management IP Interface Configure" I can configure one IP address for each VLAN. But, when I changethe  "Admin Status" from "Up" to "Down it works for both interfaces instead of just one and I kicked out myself from the WebGUI. How can I get this configuration running using just one of these Management IP Interfaces?

I tried to revoke/change my selection via serial console, "_cmdline-mode on" and "SYS". There are a lot of CLI commands available, but sadly not documentation available on the web. Searched 4 hours now using Google and gave up. Just old ProCurve CLI documentations are available, using "enable" and "config" mode (I know form former times ... and from CISCO routers).

But, back to my inital question: How can I configure the 1920 for 2 port based VLANs using only interface in one VLAN for WebLogin?

Any ideas, hints, etc.?

Thanks in advance and greetinx

priesemut

Comment: You probably only need to configure an address in the switch on the Admin VLAN. The switch can switch multiple VLANs but it only needs an address in the VLAN used for switch management.

Comment: So I just have to remove the IP address from the VLAN I don't want to use for management access? Hopefully this will work because the wizzard normally asks for an IP address on creating a new VLAN.

Anyway, thanks for your reply. I'll try it!

Greetinx,

priesemut

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using HP 1920 switches in a similar setup to yours. As stated by @Ron Maupin you only need a VLAN interface for the VLAN you would like to administer the switch on. Usually this is VLAN 1. Define your VLANs under Network > VLAN (in my case: 1 MGMT VLAN, 2 CUST VLAN, 3 GUEST VLAN) and assign the ports as desired. Under Network > VLAN Interface assign or change the IP address for the management Interface. The factory defaults contain already a VLAN Interface on VLAN 1.